# Reading the last 2 lines of a .log file via Matlab

Tags: matlab

The problem that I am attempting to solve is as follows:

I have a .log file that is updated every x seconds (an interval that I can change), with updated status information from a piece of test equipment. At each interval, another line is added to the .log file, with the updated information. My goal is to have the most recent status information  (the last two lines of the .log file) easily viewable in Matlab.

Here is an example of what each update looks like, in case that is relevant (a single line of text):

What I have tried:

I used the readtable command (shown below) to view the information in the .log file, but that gives me the entire .log file every time the function is called, when I only want/need the last two lines.

```
data = readtable('FileName.log','FileType','text')
```

I know that this would be simpler if I was working with a .csv or .xlsx file, but the test equipment only updates the .log file, so I cannot just change the file type, as it would not get updates then.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: If the matlab is continuously running, you could read to the end and then repeatedly fseek to that location and try to read again.

Comment: I agree with @L.ScottJohnson's solution. A worse alternative: rename the file (filename_N.log) after each read, I assume the logging will create a new file if it is not present. Then you can poll for the new file, process the data and rename again. Once you are finished, concatenate all of the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the .log file is in plain text format (as I assume based on your code snippet), you can get the last 2 lines of the file by using the following system command in MATLAB:

`[status,output] = system(['tail -n 2 ', path]);`

Please do keep in mind that this requires the `tail` command to be available, which is not available in windows by default - however you can get around this by installing a package containing the `tail` command, for example [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/).

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to answer here!